# Breeze client not showing entity name

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, breeze, single-page-application

Why is breeze.js not showing entity type names with some of my entities but they are in the metadata instead it gives the entity the following name 'proto._setCtor.proto'. When ever I do an api call that returns an iqueryable of a specific entity, the client shows the results as of type 'proto._setCtor.proto'. Below is an example of my mapping.

```
public class printer
{
   public Guid PrinterId { get; set; }
   public string SerialNumber { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<StaffModel> StaffModels { get; set; }
}

public class Staff
{
   public Guid StaffId { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }

   public int PrinterId { get; set; }
   public virtual Printer Printer { get; set; }
}

public class StaffMap
{
  //all is in a constructor
  ToTable("tblStaff");
  HasKey(x =>x.StaffId);

  Property(x =>x.StaffId);
  Property(x =>x.PrinterId);

  HasOptional(x =>x.printer).WithMany(x=>x.StaffModels).HasForeignKey(x =>x.StaffId);

}
```

When ever I make a call to the web api(Printers) which returns an IQueryable using breeze the returned entiry type is 'proto._setCtor.proto. If ever I remove the mapping the returned entity type is off type object which is what I want. I am planning to extend the Printer entity on the model but i can not do that if breeze returns 'proto._setCtor.proto' as an entity type.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the #C class definitions but I'm not clear what you're trying to do.

Yes the type of the returned object is a funny internal Breeze type named "proto._ctor.proto". That's the constructor that Breeze uses when it creates instances of entities which do not have custom constructors. If you [created a custom constructor](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/extending-entities) for it, you would see that name instead.

But this shouldn't hinder you. Try putting a breakpoint in the success callback for a simple query. The following returns a clean `EntityType` for me:

```
data.results[0].entityType;
```

> This returns the same results in both KO and Angular models.

This is the `EntityType` that you would extend by creating a custom constructor in the manner described in ["Extending Entities"](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/extending-entities). You don't extend the instance itself nor the Breeze default constructor.